# How can i get the object in django admin change_list template

Tags: python, django

I want to override the django admin change_list page but i am not able to find how to get the actual object so that i can access the proerties like `object.name`

In the template they have this code

`<tr >{% for item in result %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}</tr>`

where is the actual object which i can use

EDIT:

It look like `result` is the row and item is the column. i want something like `result.pk`

This yield the list if results

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py#L175

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The context fed to `change_list.html` includes a `cl` entry corresponding to a `contrib.admin.views.main.ChangeList` object, which is the object containing the result list.

You can access the result list directly like this:

```
{% for object in cl.result_list %}
{{ object.field }}
{% endfor %}
```

The change list results are rendered as part of the `change_list_results.html` template through use of the `result_list` template tag.  The `change_list_results.html` template also has the `cl` context variable present when rendering the template.

When the Django template is iterating over `result` in your example, `result` is a `ResultList` object which contains pre-rendered html, the underlying object which is being rendered is not made available.

To override the template at this level, it's likely you'll need to implement your own `result_list` type template tag which can return a list of results with the underlying objects attached as an attribute to each result.

In short it is likely that you will need to:

- Create your own `result_list` template tag, based on the Django's implementation.  Rather than have it return a `results` context as a list of `ResultList` prerendered html, have it return `results` containing objects which are both capable of being rendered to html, as well as each item having the original underlying object attached for later use in your template.
- Override the `change_list.html` template to use your new tag rather than Django's `result_list` template tag.
- Override the `change_list_results.html` template to make use of the extra information available from your template tag such as the presence of each underlying object.

As you've probably gathered, the admin app is quite tightly integrated through the layers.  Changing its operation is non-trivial and requires changes and overrides in multiple parts of the source.

Comment: It seems today that one can simply use: `cl.queryset`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also override template you use for admin with "change_list_template" and then extend change_list template.
Like

```
class NoiseFilter200Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'currencies/nf200_change_list.html'
    list_filter = ['sectors',]
    search_fields = ['name']
    #list_filter = ( MarketCapFilter )

    def market_cap_value(self, obj):
      return obj.market_cap_value > 1000000000

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        response = super().changelist_view(
            request,
            extra_context=extra_context,
        )
        try:
            qs = response.context_data['cl'].queryset
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            return response

        metrics = {
            'total_volume': Sum('volume'),
            'total_mcap': Sum('market_cap'),
        }
        response.context_data['nf_200_list'] = list(
            qs
            .values('rank','ticker','name','priceUSD','market_cap','volume','change_24h')
           # .annotate(**metrics)
            .order_by('-market_cap')[:200]
        )

        response.context_data['nf_200_totals'] = dict(
            qs.aggregate(**metrics)
        )

        return response
```

Then in your template you go like this and iterate over results and you will have a look you want

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load math_tags %}

{% block content_title %}
    <h1> Noise Filter 200 </h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block result_list %}
<style>
.results table {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

.results tbody tr{
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

.results tbody td.rank::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);;
}
</style>
    <div style="margin: 10px 0;">Total MCap today: {{ nf_200_totals.total_mcap | intword }}, Total volume today: {{ nf_200_totals.total_volume | intword }} </div>
<div class="results">
    <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="text">
            Rank
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="text">
            <a href="#">Name</a>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="text">
            <a href="#">Ticker</a>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="text">
            <a href="#">PriceUSD</a>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="text">
            <a href="#">Market cap</a>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="text">
            <a href="#">Volume</a>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="text">
            <a href="#">Change 24</a>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for row in nf_200_list %}
      <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
        <td class="rank">  </td>
        <td> {{ row.name }} </td>
        <td> {{ row.ticker }} </td>
        <td> $ {{ row.priceUSD|to_string }} </td>
        <td> {{ row.market_cap | intword }} </td>
        <td> {{ row.volume | intword }} </td>
        <td> {{ row.change_24h | percent}} </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block pagination %}{% endblock %}
```

Downside is you may use some functionality here that you get (like sorting).

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to override result_list templatetag to add object in results

1. add custom result_list tag, I named it result_list_ext

```
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list import result_headers, result_hidden_fields, ResultList, \
    items_for_result
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.base import InclusionAdminNode
from django.template import Library

register = Library()


def results(cl):
    if cl.formset:
        for res, form in zip(cl.result_list, cl.formset.forms):
            yield (res, ResultList(form, items_for_result(cl, res, form)))
    else:
        for res in cl.result_list:
            yield (res, ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None)))

def result_list(cl):
    """
    Display the headers and data list together.
    """
    headers = list(result_headers(cl))
    num_sorted_fields = 0
    for h in headers:
        if h['sortable'] and h['sorted']:
            num_sorted_fields += 1
    return {
        'cl': cl,
        'result_hidden_fields': list(result_hidden_fields(cl)),
        'result_headers': headers,
        'num_sorted_fields': num_sorted_fields,
        'results': list(results(cl)),
    }


@register.tag(name='result_list_ext')
def result_list_tag(parser, token):
    return InclusionAdminNode(
        parser, token,
        func=result_list,
        template_name='change_list_results.html',
        takes_context=False,
    )
```

Actually all that we changed here is add res in yield

```
yield (res, ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None)))
```

2. In change_list_results.html in for loop we receive result and object. That's it, now we have object in our for loop and can use it

```
{% for object, result in results %}
    {% if result.form.non_field_errors %}
        <tr id="id_{{ object.pk }}" class="grp-errors">
            <td colspan="{{ result|length }}">{{ result.form.non_field_errors }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
    <tr id="id_{{ object.pk }}" class="grp-row {% cycle 'grp-row-even' 'grp-row-odd' %}">
        {% for item in result %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

3. Use custom result_list_ext instead of django result_list and don't forget to load this new template tag in the beginning of template with load tag

```
<!-- CHANGELIST-RESULTS -->
{% block result_list %}
    {% result_list_ext cl %}
{% endblock %}
```